# Mountable Engine & Redefining views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've developed a mountable engine that has partial at xxx/admin/shared/_menu. This partial is responsible for rendering a menu.

My application defines a few controllers, which are part of the backend, and, of course, I want to include them in the menu.

It seems to me that the easiest approach is to create a partial in the engine and then override it in the (containing) application. However, when I try to use a url helper inside of it, it gives me an error.

For example:

```
 <%= admin_posts_url %>
```

Gives

```
 undefined local variable or method `admin_posts_url ' for...
```

Is there way to fix it? May be there is another good way to do it?

Comment: Did you mount the engine in the containing application? If not, the containing application would not know the engine's routes and, thus, not be able to render `admin_posts_url` (assuming you're calling that from the containing application, that is).

Comment: My partial - is part of mountable engine and my url helper is part of application. Yes, I mounted it properly

Comment: If you have not yet done so, try running `rake app:routes` in a Terminal for your engine and verify what routes are available. You can run `rake routes` in your containing application to then compare that the routes carried over, etc.

Comment: `rake routes` shows helper, but `rake app:routes` doesn't but it shouldn't do it, because this controller is defined in app where engine is mounted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails engine provides `main_app` helper to be used inside an engine by which you can refer to application's helpers.
Ref : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#routes

Try using

```
main_app.admin_posts_url
```